# Notice: Array to string conversion in basic.php on line 1443 Array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

im trying to post a query via form and im getting Notice: Array to string conversion in basic.php on line 1443 Array.

```
    function updateUSR($id, $columns, $old)
    {
        global $database;
        
        $query = '';
        $new_data = array();

        foreach($columns as $column)
            if(isset($_POST[$column['name']]) && $old[$column['name']] != $_POST[$column['name']])
            {
                $new_data[$column['name']] = $_POST[$column['name']];
                $query = $query.$column['name'].'=:'.$column['name'].', ';
                print $new_data;
            }
                
        if(strlen($query))
        {
            $query=rtrim($query,", ");
            $new_data['name'] = $id;
            
            $stmt = $database->runQueryPlayer("UPDATE users SET ".$query." WHERE a_index=:name ");
            $stmt->execute($new_data);
            $stmt->execute(); // Line 1443
            
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: which one is line 1443 - that is the only line that matters at the moment...

Comment: `print $new_data;`. You can not print arrays as a string.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error message explains the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to use print function on $new_data array . you can iterate over each value with a foreach loop and print or you can use print_r function.

```
print_r($new_data);
//or
foreach($new_data as $key => $value) {
        print($value);
}
```

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in basic.php on line 1452

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in basic.php on line 1453
Array ( [a_name] => 3864 [a_nick] => ANND01 [a_level] => 33 [a_str] => 3071 [a_dex] => 8191 [a_int] => 2571 [a_con] => 2481 [a_hp] => 98461 [a_max_hp] => 42081 [a_mp] => 62181 [a_max_mp] => 36381 )